# Stop and run recursion slider JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, slider

I am trying to understand the setTimeout method and recursion.
I have a simple slidshow based on setTimeout recursion. And I want to stop and run it by clicking on two buttons stop and play. I tried many variants, but don't understand how to clear such recursion timeout and then when I click on play, this slider runs from the slide it was stopped.

Recursion slider:

```
let timer = setTimeout(function slider() {
   
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].classList.add('hide');
    }
    currentSlide++;
    if (currentSlide > images.length) {
        currentSlide = 1;
    } 
    images[currentSlide - 1].classList.remove('hide');
    setTimeout(slider, 3000); 
}, 0);
```

Buttons:

```
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });

playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            setTimeout(timer, 3000);
        });
```

UPD: I've almost achieved the stop/play fuctionality, but when I click on play btn, slideshow continues in 2 slides. And whenever I click on play button the slideshow changes.

```
timer = setTimeout(function slider() {
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].classList.add('hide');
    }
    images[currentSlide].classList.remove('hide');
    
    if (currentSlide + 1 === images.length) {
        currentSlide = 0;
        
    } else {
        currentSlide++;
    }
    
    let sllideSwhow = setTimeout(slider, 3000);
    
    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
       clearTimeout(sllideSwhow);
    });
    playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        slider();
    });
    
}, 0);
```

Comment: playBtn should do `timer = setTimeout(slider, 0);`, you have `timer` instead of `silder` there

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've managed to do it.

```
function slider() {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].classList.add('hide');
    }
    images[currentSlide].classList.remove('hide');
    
    if (currentSlide + 1 === images.length) {
        currentSlide = 0;
        
    } else {
        currentSlide++;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(slider, 3000);
}
slider();
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    playing = 0;
 });
 playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!playing) {
        playing = 1;
        slider();
    }
 });
```